# Windows Control: drop down list still show a blank after clear all items

Tags: c++, c, windows, drop-down-menu, win32gui

I create a drop down list using pure Win32 api. First it's empty(when click, no blank rect occur), then I add 10 items into it, then clear all of them. When I click the drop down list, it show a big blank rect.

Does anyone know how to solve it?

[image]

[image: after insert items]

[image: blank drop down list]

Comment: Doesn't an empty drop-down menu feel strange? I would not be surprised if it actually violated some Windows design guideline.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably first clear and then add.